# pthreads - Join on group of threads, wait for one to exit

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

In the POSIX thread interface, `pthread_join(thread)` can be used to block until the specified thread exits.

Is there a similar function that will allow execution to block until any child thread exits?

This would be similar to the `wait()` UNIX system call, except be applicable for child threads, not a processes

Comment: I believe, as others have said, you need condition variables for this. However for related synchronization issues you might also want to read up on barriers. They offer a much simpler interface to this sort of waiting that suffices in some situations but not others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is directly possible from pthreads per se, but you can work around it fairly easily.

Using the pthreads API, you can use `pthread_cond_wait` and friends to set up a "condition" and wait on it. When a thread is about to exit, signal the condition to wakeup the waiting thread.

Alternatively, another method is to create a pipe with `pipe`, and when a thread is going to exit, `write` to the pipe. Have the main thread waiting on the other end of the pipe with either `select`, `poll`, `epoll`, or your favorite variant thereof. (This also allows you to wait simultaneously on other FDs.)

Newer versions of Linux also include "eventfds" for doing the same thing, see `man eventfd`, but note this is only recently added. Note that is isn't POSIX, it's Linux-only, and it's only available if you're reasonably up-to-date. (2.6.22 or better.)

I've personally always wondered why this API wasn't designed to treat these things similar to file descriptors. If it were me, they'd be "eventables", and you could `select` files, threads, timers...

Comment: "If it were me, they'd be "eventables", and you could select files, threads, timers." +1 : WinAPI really has the edge here with being able to call `WaitOnSingleObject` or `WaitOnMultipleObjects` on practically everything.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any function in the POSIX thread interface to do this.

You'd need to create your own version of it - e.g. an array of flags (one flag per thread) protected by a mutex and a condition variable; where just before "pthread_exit()" each thread acquires the mutex, sets its flag, then does "pthread_cond_signal()". The main thread waits for the signal, then checks the array of flags to determine which thread/s to join (there may be more than one thread to join by then).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a customize one by pthread conditional variable: pthread_cond_wait(), pthread_cond_signal()/pthread_cond_broadcast().