# The version of pthread_join() that does not block main(): POSIX

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I am trying to write a code that does not block `main()` when `pthread_join()` is called:
i.e. basically trying to implement my previous question mentioned below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509500/pthread-join-and-main-blocking-multithreading

And the corresponding explanation at:

[pthreads - Join on group of threads, wait for one to exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577471/pthreads-join-on-group-of-threads-wait-for-one-to-exit)

As per suggested answer:

`You'd need to create your own version of it - e.g. an array of flags (one flag per thread) protected by a mutex and a condition variable; where just before "pthread_exit()" each thread acquires the mutex, sets its flag, then does "pthread_cond_signal()". The main thread waits for the signal, then checks the array of flags to determine which thread/s to join (there may be more than one thread to join by then).`

I have tried as below:

My status array which keeps a track of which threads have finished:

```
typedef struct {
    int Finish_Status[THREAD_NUM];
    int signalled;

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t FINISHED;
    }THREAD_FINISH_STATE;
```

The thread routine, it sets the corresponding array element when the thread finishes and also signals the condition variable:

```
void* THREAD_ROUTINE(void* arg)
{
    THREAD_ARGUMENT* temp=(THREAD_ARGUMENT*) arg;
    printf("Thread created with id %d\n",temp->id);
    waitFor(5);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
    ThreadFinishStatus.Finish_Status[temp->id]=TRUE;
    ThreadFinishStatus.signalled=TRUE;
    if(ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==TRUE)
    {
      pthread_cond_signal(&(ThreadFinishStatus.FINISHED));
      printf("Signal that thread %d finished\n",temp->id);
     }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));

    pthread_exit((void*)(temp->id));
    }
```

I am not able to write the corresponding parts `pthread_join()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` functions. There are a few things which I am not able to implement.

1) How to write corresponding part `pthread_cond_wait()` in my `main()`?

2) I am trying to write it as:

```
   pthread_mutex_lock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
    while((ThreadFinishStatus.signalled != TRUE){
     pthread_cond_wait(&(ThreadFinishStatus.FINISHED), &(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
     printf("Main Thread signalled\n");
     ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==FALSE; //Reset signalled
     //check which thread to join
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
```

But it does not enter the while loop.

3) How to use `pthread_join()` so that I can get the return value stored in my `arg[i].returnStatus`
i.e. where to put below statement in my main:

```
`pthread_join(T[i],&(arg[i].returnStatus));`
```

**COMPLETE CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

#define THREAD_NUM 5
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1


void waitFor (unsigned int secs) {
    time_t retTime;
    retTime = time(0) + secs;     // Get finishing time.
    while (time(0) < retTime);    // Loop until it arrives.
}

typedef struct {
    int Finish_Status[THREAD_NUM];
    int signalled;

    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t FINISHED;
    }THREAD_FINISH_STATE;

typedef struct {
    int id;
    void* returnStatus;
    }THREAD_ARGUMENT;

THREAD_FINISH_STATE ThreadFinishStatus;

void initializeState(THREAD_FINISH_STATE* state)
{
 int i=0;
 state->signalled=FALSE;
 for(i=0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++)
 {
     state->Finish_Status[i]=FALSE;
     }
 pthread_mutex_init(&(state->mutex),NULL);
 pthread_cond_init(&(state->FINISHED),NULL);
    }

void destroyState(THREAD_FINISH_STATE* state)
{
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++)
 {
     state->Finish_Status[i]=FALSE;
     }
 pthread_mutex_destroy(&(state->mutex));
 pthread_cond_destroy(&(state->FINISHED));
    }


void* THREAD_ROUTINE(void* arg)
{
    THREAD_ARGUMENT* temp=(THREAD_ARGUMENT*) arg;
    printf("Thread created with id %d\n",temp->id);
    waitFor(5);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
    ThreadFinishStatus.Finish_Status[temp->id]=TRUE;
    ThreadFinishStatus.signalled=TRUE;
    if(ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==TRUE)
    {
      pthread_cond_signal(&(ThreadFinishStatus.FINISHED));
      printf("Signal that thread %d finished\n",temp->id);
     }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));

    pthread_exit((void*)(temp->id));
    }

int main()
{
    THREAD_ARGUMENT arg[THREAD_NUM];
    pthread_t T[THREAD_NUM];
    int i=0;
    initializeState(&ThreadFinishStatus);

    for(i=0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++)
    {
        arg[i].id=i;
        }

    for(i=0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++)
        {
            pthread_create(&T[i],NULL,THREAD_ROUTINE,(void*)&arg[i]);
        }

    /*
     Join only if signal received
    */

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
    //Wait
    while((ThreadFinishStatus.signalled != TRUE){
     pthread_cond_wait(&(ThreadFinishStatus.FINISHED), &(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
     printf("Main Thread signalled\n");
     ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==FALSE; //Reset signalled
     //check which thread to join
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));

    destroyState(&ThreadFinishStatus);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Depending on platform, you could use (the non-portable) [`pthread_tryjoin_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html) function.

Comment: Will it require too much re-coding to create detached threads?

Comment: Works as expected, prints "blah blah Main Thread signalled" and exits. What do you observe?

Comment: There are race conditions in that code, depending on how fast threads finish. Use a counting semaphore that the threads increment when they finish, that the main decrements to find out when threads are finished. Protect access to the shared data structure using a vanilla mutex. Acquring the mutex just to immediately release it in a cond is silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a program that uses a counting semaphore to watch as threads finish, find out which thread it was, and review some result data from that thread. This program is efficient with locks - waiters are not spuriously woken up (notice how the threads only post to the semaphore *after* they've released the mutex protecting shared state).

This design allows the main program to process the result from some thread's computation immediately after the thread completes, and does not require the main wait for all threads to complete. This would be especially helpful if the running time of each thread varied by a significant amount.

Most importantly, this program does not deadlock nor race.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>

void* ThreadEntry(void* args );

typedef struct {
    int threadId;
    pthread_t thread;
    int threadResult;
} ThreadState;

sem_t           completionSema;

pthread_mutex_t resultMutex;

std::queue<int> threadCompletions;

ThreadState* threadInfos;

int main() {

    int numThreads = 10;
    int* threadResults;
    void* threadResult;
    int doneThreadId;


    sem_init( &completionSema, 0, 0 );

    pthread_mutex_init( &resultMutex, 0 );

    threadInfos = new ThreadState[numThreads];

    for ( int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ ) {

        threadInfos[i].threadId = i;
        pthread_create( &threadInfos[i].thread, NULL, &ThreadEntry, &threadInfos[i].threadId  );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++ ) {
        // Wait for any one thread to complete; ie, wait for someone
        // to queue to the threadCompletions queue.
        sem_wait( &completionSema );


        // Find out what was queued; queue is accessed from multiple threads,
        // so protect with a vanilla mutex.
        pthread_mutex_lock(&resultMutex);
        doneThreadId = threadCompletions.front();
        threadCompletions.pop();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&resultMutex);

        // Announce which thread ID we saw finish
        printf(
            "Main saw TID %d finish\n\tThe thread's result was %d\n",
            doneThreadId,
            threadInfos[doneThreadId].threadResult
        );

        // pthread_join to clean up the thread.
        pthread_join( threadInfos[doneThreadId].thread, &threadResult );
    }

    delete threadInfos;

    pthread_mutex_destroy( &resultMutex );
    sem_destroy( &completionSema );

}

void* ThreadEntry(void* args ) {
    int threadId = *((int*)args);

    printf("hello from thread %d\n", threadId );

    // This can safely be accessed since each thread has its own space
    // and array derefs are thread safe.
    threadInfos[threadId].threadResult = rand() % 1000;


    pthread_mutex_lock( &resultMutex );
    threadCompletions.push( threadId );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &resultMutex );

    sem_post( &completionSema );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pthread conditions don't have "memory"; pthread_cond_wait doesn't return if pthread_cond_signal is called before pthread_cond_wait, which is why it's important to check the predicate before calling pthread_cond_wait, and not call it if it's true. But that means the action, in this case "check which thread to join" should only depend on the predicate, not on whether pthread_cond_wait is called.

Also, you might want to make the while loop actually wait for all the threads to terminate, which you aren't doing now.

(Also, I think the other answer about "signalled==FALSE" being harmless is wrong, it's not harmless, because there's a pthread_cond_wait, and when that returns, signalled would have changed to true.)

So if I wanted to write a program that waited for all threads to terminate this way, it would look more like

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
// AllThreadsFinished would check that all of Finish_Status[] is true
// or something, or simpler, count the number of joins completed
while (!AllThreadsFinished()) {
  // Wait, keeping in mind that the condition might already have been
  // signalled, in which case it's too late to call pthread_cond_wait,
  // but also keeping in mind that pthread_cond_wait can return spuriously,
  // thus using a while loop
  while (!ThreadFinishStatus.signalled) {
    pthread_cond_wait(&(ThreadFinishStatus.FINISHED), &(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
  }
  printf("Main Thread signalled\n");
  ThreadFinishStatus.signalled=FALSE; //Reset signalled
  //check which thread to join
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));
```

Comment: I disagree with your analysis. `signalled==FALSE` is harmless because it has no effect. You're quite correct that signalled might not be false, but that's fine. The line of code does nothing, so it won't mess up signalled in any case.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The answer to which I was referring said it was harmless because signalled was always false, which is wrong (though I think it's edited now). Second, a mistake which turns a line of code that *should* do something into a line that *doesn't* is in no way something I would consider harmless for the functionality of the code.

Comment: I do agree, however, that using signalled this way (explicit resets) is not good style, as it can be difficult to get right (in this case, there might be more than one thread waiting to join for every reset, and the signal isn't resignaled if you fail to handle that). It might be safer if the inner loop checked the ThreadFinishStatus array (or some equivalent) directly, and got rid of "signalled" entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears fine. You have one minor buglet:

```
 ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==FALSE; //Reset signalled
```

This does nothing. It tests whether signalled is FALSE and throws away the result. That's harmless though since there's nothing you need to do. (You *never* want to set `signalled` to `FALSE` because that loses the fact that it was signalled. There is never any reason to unsignal it -- if a thread finished, then it's finished forever.)

Not entering the `while` loop means `signalled` is TRUE. That means the thread already set it, in which case there is no need to enter the loop because there's nothing to wait for. So that's fine.

Also:

```
ThreadFinishStatus.signalled=TRUE;
if(ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==TRUE)
```

There's no need to test the thing you just set. It's not like the set can fail.

FWIW, I would suggest re-architecting. If the existing functions like `pthread_join` don't do exactly what you want, just don't use them. If you're going to have structures that track what work is done, then totally separate that from thread termination. Since you will already know what work is done, what different does it make when and how threads terminate? Don't think of this as "I need a special way to know when a thread terminates" and instead think of this "I need to know what work is done so I can do other things".

Comment: Actually my requirement is as soon as a thread finishes (Out of the 5 threads), I want to perform some task in `main()` based on the return value of the just finished thread.
If I use join like this-
`for(i=0;i<THREAD_NUM;i++){pthread_join(T[i],&(arg[i].returnStatus));
printf("Main resumed after Thread Finished :%d\n",arg[i].returnStatus);}`
Suppose if `thread 2` finishes first; my `main()` will be blocked untill `threads 0 and 1` are finished and I can not immediately process the result returned by `thread 2`; This is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @GauravK That's what I figured. Then my comments are correct. You can check if each thread is finished by acquiring the mutex and checking the `signalled` variable.

Comment: @@David I am having trouble with this part of code- `while((ThreadFinishStatus.signalled != TRUE){pthread_cond_wait(&(ThreadFinishStatus.FINISHED), &(ThreadFinishStatus.mutex));printf("Main Thread signalled\n");ThreadFinishStatus.signalled==FALSE; //Reset signalled//check which thread to join /*Put the join statement here*/}`. I mean I am not able to implement that as soon as a task finishes, check the return value for only that particular thread; `To obtain the return value I must use pthread_join()`

Comment: @GauravK If it's bothering you, have the thread stash its return value in the structure. If `pthread_join` doesn't work *exactly* the way you want it to, just don't use it. It doesn't do anything you can't do yourself (other than reap the thread, which you can just detach if you want).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is racy.

Suppose you start a thread and it finishes before you grab the mutex in `main()`.  Your `while` loop will never run because `signalled` was already set to `TRUE` by the exiting thread.

I will echo @antiduh's suggestion to use a semaphore that counts the number of dead-but-not-joined threads.  You then loop up to the number of threads spawned waiting on the semaphore.  I'd point out that the POSIX `sem_t` is not like a `pthread_mutex` in that `sem_wait` can return EINTR.

Comment: I totally disagree with you analysis. True, the while loop will not run, but why should it in that case? The point of the while loop is to exit when the thread finishes, which is exactly what it does in this case.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: It starts more than one thread...  (Edit:  It appears that the two of us do not agree about what the code is supposed to do.  You answered "wait for one" and I gave a partial answer to "wait for all."  I'm not clear on which one OP wants, since he links to "wait for one" posts but his code looks like an attempt at 'wait for all.")

Comment: If he just wants to wait for all threads, blocking until they're all don, he can use `pthread_join`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, unless he wants to clean them up as soon as they're done.