# How to wait two pthreads?

Tags: c++, pthreads, pthread-join

Would any one please tell me what happens between the last two code lines

```
// Creating Server and Client threads
pthread_create(&serverThread, NULL, (void* (*)(void*))&Server,(void *)0);

pthread_create(&clientThread, NULL, (void* (*)(void*))&Client,(void *)1);

// Wait until serverThread exits
pthread_join( serverThread, NULL);

// Wait until clientThread exits
pthread_join( clientThread, NULL);
```

I want to wait them simultaneously. What if one of the two threads terminates/exits? What if server kept running in an infinite loop?

Comment: please tell us what you error is.

Comment: I am not talking about an error :) My question is: What happens between the last two code lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pthreads - Join on group of threads, wait for one to exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577471/pthreads-join-on-group-of-threads-wait-for-one-to-exit)

Comment: look here http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#CREATIONTERMINATION. Aslo please compile your code first.

Comment: What if an asteroid hits Earth between the first and the second call to `pthread_join`? Please explain what kind of treat you are looking to avoid by simultaneos waiting. A thread can terminate, that's what most threads do, `pthread_join` lets you wait for exactly that. The other one is unclear. How simultaneous waiting would ket you recover from an infinite loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first join - `pthread_join(serverThread, NULL);` will wait until *serverThread* terminates.

The *clientThread* may or may not terminate during this time; if it terminates, it remains in zombie state until `pthread_join(clientThread, NULL);` gets called. `pthread_join` will return immediately in this case.

If *clientThread* has not yet finished execution when `pthread_join(clientThread, NULL);` is called, it will wait again until `clientThread` terminates.